# Who generates Mongodb _id (ObjectId) field's value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If I insert a document, directly with a mongodb client or with Mongoose, who is responsible to generate the `_id` field's value? Is it happening inside the database engine or the clients do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique `_id` field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the `_id` field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an `ObjectId` for the `_id` field.

> **Note**
>   Most MongoDB driver clients will include the `_id` field and generate an `ObjectId` before sending the `insert` operation to MongoDB; however, if the client sends a document without an `_id` field, the `mongod` will add the `_id` field and generate the `ObjectId`.

<sub>https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#the-id-field</sub>